# How to add a clickable hyperlink in latex so that it references to a specific paragraph in the same article?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I would like to make a calender with clickable links that would reference me to another section in the same article. Currently, the code I have been using to generate the calender is as follows.

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{termcal}
\newcommand{\TRClass}{
\calday[Mon]{\classday} % mon
\calday[Tue]{\classday} % Tuesday
\calday[Wed]{\classday} % wed
%\skipday % Wednesday (no class)
\calday[Thur]{\classday} % Thursday
\calday[Fri]{\classday}
\calday[Sat]{\classday}
\calday[Sun]{\classday}
%\skipday % Friday 
%\skipday\skipday % weekend (no class)
}


\begin{document}
\title{title}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\section{plans}
\paragraph*{Tentative Schedule:}
\begin{center}
\begin{calendar}{9/4/2023}{16} 
\setlength{\calboxdepth}{.3in}
\TRClass
% schedule
\caltexton{1}
\caltextnext{}
\caltextnext{}



\caltext{9/8/2023}{\hyperref[]{Specific plans}
\label{foo}{RDU-NYC; PEK-NYC}}
\end{calendar}
\end{center}
\section{Specific plans}

\end{document}
```

I would like to be able to click on "RDU-NYC; PEK-NYC" and jump to the section "Specific plans". Thank you for reading through all this.

Comment: See `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` (hyperref manual, page 24).

Comment: Resolved. I just wasn't sure how to use hyperref in the caltext function